# Debugging gitignore not untracking files

Tags: git

I've added a pattern both to .gitignore and to .git/info/exclude. File matching pattern still shows up under git status` as an untracked file. How can I debug this?

Comment: git: 'check-ignore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: What version of git are you running and on what platform?

Comment: git version 1.7.10.4 Debian

Comment: That version is archaic in git terms (June 2012).  Upgrade to a newer version, or just borrow a version of `check-ignore` from a newer version to  sort out your current issue.

Comment: I didn't realize debian's version of git was so old. I should have said: "git: 'check-ignore' is not a git command in my version of git"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Andrew C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021077/andrew-c) told you **[`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)** will check your ignored files.

If you want to debug the git command and see what it actually executing use the `GIT_TRACE=1`

Go over the different **[`GIT_TRACE`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git)** flags and turn them on/off for your needs if you want to debug more then just the ignored files